# Android Photo Tagging

Tags: android, android-camera, android-photos

I'm creating an Android App with Camera a utility.

I want to tag a person or add clickable annotations over the image.

When i came across the overlay or gesture drawing over the image and the following link, 
[Tag photos on Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495046/tag-photos-on-android-app)

i have the couple of doubts that needs some clarity.

1. How to add clickable view over the image as in the case for annotations
2. How to persists the annotations, so that it is available when ever i open it via my app.

Kindly share me some idea.

--
Siva

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this, Siva? I'm stuck in the same position - looking for a simple arrow/circle annotation. Any tips would be great, thanks!

Comment: @JoshPinter No improvements!

Comment: Thanks for getting back. If I come up with a solid solution I'll post here for others.

Comment: No update on this? Would like to know too.

Comment: @AimanB No, couldn't find an optimal solution.